# How can I detach the zipper pulls on my suitcase and attach them to zipper sliders?

Tags: travel, zipper

I broke the pulls away from the sliders of my suitcase's zipper. 
Now I hope to detach pulls from other sliders rarely used, and attach them to the previous sliders.

In order to detach a pull from a slider, I was thinking to make a little bigger the tiny opening between the slider and the hook using pliers, so that I can drag the pull off the slider. But my friend said that the connection of the hook and the slider at the other end is rigid, and making the opening a little bigger might break the connection.

So I was wondering, ow can I detach a pull from a slider with damaging both and then attach the pull to another slider?

[image]

Comment: I love the idea of using flame to make the metal more bendy, but I doubt it's a great idea near your suitcase :(

Comment: If you only want a replacement use a bit of wire, or a paperclip. You can also buy replacement tabs in sewing shops.

Answer (score 6):

If your zipper is anything like the one in the picture, you can see a seam on it that indicates that it is moulded or sintered rather than machined or pressed from a tempered metal. This means it is brittle so applying to much force will cause it to  snap rather than bend. A safer option would be to attach a split ring from a key ring.